The equation $x^5 - 2x^4 - 1 = 0$ has five complex roots $a, b, c, d, e$ . Find the value of $\sum \frac{1}{a^8}$.

The equation $x^5 - 2x^4 - 1 = 0$ has five complex roots $a, b, c, d, e$ . Find the value of $\frac{1}{a^8} + \frac{1}{b^8} + \frac{1}{c^8} + \frac{1}{d^8} + \frac{1}{e^8}$ .

I know so far Newton's identity can be used to find power sum of roots if the power is non negative but no idea what to do in this case as that identity don't work here nor reducing $a^8$ in terms of degree 5 or 4 expression making it not simple to manipulate later . Any hints ??

Hint: $x^5-2x^4-1$ has exactly one real root $e$, and $b=\overline{a}, d=\overline{c}$ with complex conjugated roots $a, b, c, d $ . We have  $\frac{1}{a^8} + \frac{1}{b^8} + \frac{1}{c^8} + \frac{1}{d^8} + \frac{1}{e^8}=16$. This is proved at art of problem solving.

You can also use the fact that if $a,b,c,d,e$ are the roots of a quintic $f(x)$, then $1/a,1/b,1/c,1/d,1/e$ are the roots of the quintic $\tilde{f}(x)=x^5f(1/x)$. This may be simpler to use when you observe that $\tilde{f}(x)$ has the same sequence of coefficient as $f(x)$ but in the reverse order. So here
$$\tilde{f}(x)=-x^5-2x+1.$$

FYI, numerically, the roots are $2.055967396712819$, $-0.5821701007901724 \pm 0.5263901664272871i$, and $0.554186402433763 \pm 0.6945926545524447i$, giving an answer of $16$.  But I assume you want an algebraic approach to a solution.

Let $a_i$ be the roots of the equation $x^5-2x^4-1=0$, where $a_1=a,a_2=b, a_3=c,a_4=d,a_5=e$.
Then, $a_i^5-2a_i^4-1=a_i^4(a_i-2)-1=0\implies \frac{1}{a_i^4}=a_i-2\implies\frac{1}{a_i^8}=(a_i-2)^2$.
Now, $$\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{a^8}+\frac{1}{b^8}+\frac{1}{c^8}+\frac{1}{d^8}+\frac{1}{e^8}=\sum_i\frac{1}{a_i^8}&=\sum_i(a_i-2)^2\\&=\sum_i(a_i^2-4a_i+4)\\&=\left(\sum_i a_i\right)^2-2\sum_{i\neq j} a_ia_j-4\sum_ia_i+5\cdot4\\&=2^2-2\cdot0-4\cdot2+20\\\color{red}{\frac{1}{a^8}+\frac{1}{b^8}+\frac{1}{c^8}+\frac{1}{d^8}+\frac{1}{e^8}}&\color{red}{=16}
\end{aligned}$$

Just another way which always works when you have 'separable' expressions, using Extended Euclidean algorithm: [or by noting $(x^5-2x^4)^2-1 = x^8(x-2)^2-1$]
$$\color{red}{x^8}(x-2)^2-\color{blue}{(x^5-2x^4-1)}(x^5-2x^4+1)=1$$
$$\implies \frac1{\color{red}{x^8}}\equiv (x-2)^2 \pmod{\color{blue}{x^5-2x^4-1}}$$
$$\implies \sum \frac1{a^8} = \sum a^2-4\sum a+4\sum 1$$
where $\sum$ sums over all five roots.  By Vieta, $\sum a=2, \sum a^2=(\sum a)^2-2(\sum ab)=4$ hence $$\sum \frac1{a^8}=4-4\times2+4\times5=16$$
